# Ubuntu 14.04 does not start installation

Tags: system-installation, kernel, usb-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a PC with UEFI and windows 8.1 x64. I am using a usb installation, ubuntu starts and show initial purple screen, after I get the following screen [image]

And the PC frozen here. What is happening? My PC has an ASUS motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, did you disable Safe Boot/Fast Boot? If not, do so.

Second, check your install medium. If there are any errors (bad files, scratches, etc...) Ubuntu could fail to boot.

Finally, make sure you are not using Legacy Bios/CSM with your Ubuntu UEFI install disk, it simply wouldn't boot.